# Can I manually change boxplot color with ggMarginal?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggMarginal` to make marginal boxplots. Is there a way to manually change the color and/or fill of the boxplots without a grouping variable? I'd like to have different colors on the x boxplot and the y boxplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggExtra)

foo <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=1),
                  y=rnorm(100,mean=2,sd=2))


p1 <- ggplot(data = foo,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_equal()
ggMarginal(p1, type="boxplot", size=12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I have understood you correctly, you can do the following

```r
p1 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_equal()
ggMarginal(
    p1, 
    type = "boxplot", 
    size = 12, 
    xparams = list(colour = "blue"),
    yparams = list(colour = "red"))
```

[image]